# When Object tag is display:none, method fails, but when visibility:hidden works

Tags: java, class, object

I have a `span` tag as parent to an `object` tag that loads a Java class. The `span` tag has style `display:none`.  When a reference to the `object` tag is retrieved in Javascript and a method of this `object` tag is called, it fails.

But, if the `span` tag does not have `display:none` set OR `visibility:hidden`, then it works.

Why is this?

```
<span style='display:none'>
  <object type="application/x-java-applet" width="100" height="100" name="my_class" id="my_class">
    <param name="codebase" value="http://www.whatever.com/class">
    <param name="code" value="myclass.class">
    <param name="mayscript" value="yes">
    <param name="scriptable" value="true">
 </object>
</span>
```

Comment: As an aside, your object element is malformed.  It is always advisable to validate HTML against a DTD.  HTML has structure and rules and if you throw invalid HTML into a browser, how it will be rendered is anybody's guess.

Comment: Also, consider using Oracle's `deployJava.js` instead of trying to write the applet(/object) element yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basic styles (CSS), a hidden object is still included in the page, while an element with `display:none` is not even included.

Solution:

- Make the applet around `10x10` pixels in size
- Put it in some innocuous part of the web page (e.g. at the end)
- Use **`visibility`**`:hidden` to hide it from view.  Note that is `visibility`, not `display`!

Answer (score 1):

Larry.

The reason is that when using 'display:none' browser renders the page as though the element was not there at all. Although you can get the referrence to the 'object' element in DOM, but object itself hasn't been created yet. On the other hand 'visibility:hidden' only hides the element, but it still takes up space and layout.

The best solution to not break page layout is to make your element absolutely positioned and take it in some place outside the user sight (e.g. left:-1000px)

Comment: Thanks.  I understand what is wrong now.  appreciate your comments